Missing pyarrow symbols in pybind11 extension module
I'm trying to use pybind11 to make an extension module that interacts with arrow.  Specifically, I want to provide a function that accepts an arrow::Table as an argument.  I can get the extension module to compile, but when I try to use it, I get an "undefined symbol" error for arrow::py::unwrap_table.  I know that this symbol is defined in a shared object file contained in the pyarrow package, but I can't figure out how to make my extension module find it.
I'm not even sure how exactly I should be trying to do this.  My instinct is that I want my module to find and use the shared object file included with pyarrow, so there's no chance of my module somehow being incompatible with the version of pyarrow that the user has installed.  But don't have much experience working with extension modules, and I don't know how this kind of thing is usually handled.  Is it necessary to statically link the library?  Or is there some way to tell python at runtime where to look for shared libraries?
Here's the minimal example I've been trying to debug this with:
demo.cc
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/python/pyarrow.h>

int num_rows(pybind11::object const & py_obj) {
    auto result = arrow::py::unwrap_table(py_obj.ptr());
    if (not result.ok()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("argument must be an Arrow table");
    }
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = result.ValueOrDie();
    return table->num_rows();
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(df_test, m)
{
    arrow::py::import_pyarrow();
    m.def("num_rows", &num_rows);
}

pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = [
  "setuptools>=42",
  "pybind11>2.10",
  "pyarrow",
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "demo"
description = ""
version = "0.0.0"
dependencies = ["pyarrow"]

setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
import pyarrow as pa

setup(
        ext_modules=[
            Pybind11Extension(
                name='demo',
                sources=[
                    'demo.cc',
                ],
                include_dirs=[pa.get_include()],

                # I tried including these two lines, but they didn't have any 
                # effect.  The `pa.get_library_dirs()` paths are to the 
                # temporary build environment created by pip anyways, so I 
                # don't think they would be helpful unless I was going for 
                # static linking.
                #libraries=pa.get_libraries(),
                #library_dirs=pa.get_library_dirs(),

                cxx_std=17,
            ),
        ],
)

Generating the error:
$ python -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip install .
...
Successfully installed demo-0.0.0 numpy-1.26.4 pyarrow-16.1.0
$ python -c "import demo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/kale/hacking/snippets/python/pybind11_arrow/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/demo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5arrow2py12unwrap_tableEP7_object

Confirming the location of the undefined symbol:
$ nm -gD venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow_python.so | grep unwrap_table
000000000019ad00 T _ZN5arrow2py12unwrap_tableEP7_object


Arrow doesn't look like a header-only library, so you definitely need to link with something, be it static or dynamic.

After much frustration, I figured out two ways to make this work.  It turns out that I had a few things wrong.
Compile time:
The first problem is linking to the shared libraries at compile time.  The code I gave above, with the libraries and library_dirs settings commented out, basically just skips this step entirely.  In retrospect, I don't understand why the linking step succeeds without these settings.  But ignoring that, the "undefined symbol" errors at runtime are because the linking never happened.
To fix this, I had to uncomment the aforementioned library settings.  But I also had to call pyarrow.create_library_symlinks() before setup().  This command makes a number of symlinks in the directory where pyarrow package is installed, similar to the following:
$ ls -l /path/to/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyarrow
...
libarrow.so -> /path/to/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.1601
...

Without these links, the linker will not find the pyarrow libraries.  I think the problem is that the shared object files in the pyarrow directory all have version number suffixes (e.g. 1601 in the above example), and the linker is looking for unsuffixed files.
I was initially concerned that pa.get_library_dirs() would return paths to the pyarrow installation in the build environment, not the install environment.  I had a similar concern about pa.create_library_symlinks().  Because it's called in setup.py, the symlinks are created in the build environment only.  However, I came to realize that all of this information—the library directories and the symlinks—is only needed at compile time.  The compiled extension module will only contain the names of the libraries (with version numbers), and a separate process will be used to find those libraries at runtime.
Runtime:
The second problem is finding the necessary arrow/pyarrow symbols at runtime.  I found two ways to do this.  The first is to include the path to the site-packages/pyarrow directory in the compiled executable itself.  The second is just to always import pyarrow before importing the extension module.  I'm not sure which of these approaches is better.
First approach:
The first approach requires adding to the executable's rpath, which is a list of directories to search for shared libraries.  I knew nothing about rpath when I asked this question, but this article was really informative.  In order to make this work, I had to know where my extension module would be installed, and where the pyarrow directory would be relative to that.  Here's what the site-packages directory looks like:
$ ls /path/to/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/
...
pyarrow
...
demo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

In the context of rpath on Linux, $ORIGIN is the directory containing the executable itself.  So the appropriate rpath in this particular case would be $ORIGIN/pyarrow.  However, if the extension module were part of a package (which is probably the more common case), the rpath would have to be $ORIGIN/../pyarrow or something like that.
The -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/pyarrow argument tells the compiler to set the rpath.  In setuptools, the extra_link_args setting can be used to provide this argument.  For different systems, the exact details of this step are probably different.
Below is the complete setup.py for this approach:
from setuptools import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
import pyarrow as pa

pa.create_library_symlinks()
setup(
        ext_modules=[
            Pybind11Extension(
                name='demo',
                sources=['demo.cc'],
                include_dirs=[pa.get_include()],
                libraries=pa.get_libraries(),
                library_dirs=pa.get_library_dirs(),
                extra_link_args=[
                    "-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/pyarrow",
                ],
                cxx_std=17,
            ),
        ],
)

When I was debugging this approach, I found the following commands helpful.  readelf shows the information actually stored in the executable itself, and ldd shows how the shared library names get resolved to paths:
$ readelf -d /path/to/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/demo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
$ ldd /path/to/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/demo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Second approach:
An alternative to mucking around with rpath is apparently to just ignore the whole thing, and always import pyarrow before the extension module.  I don't know for sure why this works, but I assume that importing pyarrow causes all the necessary shared libraries to be loaded, at which point they're available to the extension module—despite the fact that the extension module itself doesn't contain enough information to find the libraries.
The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require worrying about platform-specific compiler flags, and it doesn't require knowing the exact relative path to the directory where a third-party package is installed.  The downside is that it feels a bit sketchy to deliberately compile an executable that can't work on its own.  It also makes it hard for users to directly import the extension module, although having a pure-python wrapper module is not that much of a burden.
Below is the complete setup.py for this approach:
from setuptools import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
import pyarrow as pa

pa.create_library_symlinks()
setup(
        ext_modules=[
            Pybind11Extension(
                name='demo',
                sources=['demo.cc'],
                include_dirs=[pa.get_include()],
                libraries=pa.get_libraries(),
                library_dirs=pa.get_library_dirs(),
                cxx_std=17,
            ),
        ],
)

Here's a script that demonstrates the order that the modules have to be imported in:
import pyarrow as pa
import demo
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
print(demo.num_rows(df.to_arrow()))

Useful links:

pybind11_arrow: This is a repository I made containing all the files described in this question and answer.

turbodbc/setup.py: This is a real-life open source project that uses pybind11 and arrow.  I found it helpful to read its setup.py file.

Relevant pyarrow documentation:  Somehow I overlooked this page initially.  In retrospect it contains a lot of the information I was missing, but I don't know if I would've been able to understand it before I went through this whole debugging process myself.


