package python module with pybind11 extension that depends on shared libraries
I'm using pybind11 to create cross platform bindings to the c++ library named piper-phonemize.
The library depends on 2 native libraries - onnxruntime and espeak-ng.
There's cmake file which produce the needed shared libraries.
However, I cannot find a simple way to include these shared libraries in Windows/Linux/macOS.
I use pyproject.toml and setup.py
I would like to place the native pybind11 extension along with the shared libraries in the package folder. Is there a simple way to include them in a way that the extension will be able to load them once I import the extension?
Thanks

I asked a similar question recently. It might be helpful to you, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78500745/missing-pyarrow-symbols-in-pybind11-extension-module

I used uv to to create the package. for adding shared libraries I simply placed them in src folder of the package and called uv build. And then the shared libraries available after users install the package in the same folder of the package.

To achieve the goal if we use Windows 11 (my case) you can first install the necessary tools such as CMake: https://cmake.org/download/ (This can allow you to run the GUI of CMake) https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Getting%20Started.html#running-the-cmake-gui
Using the pybind11 library will require a setuptools build script and a build command from CMD, my file structure is the below:

python s\pythoncompilation.py build

To avoid getting an error on source code I added the full path to the script nevertheless the python3.8 installation had the pybind11 library previously installed specifically to that installation (not a global installation):

Last you use python setuptools and build the libraries:
#pythoncompilation.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("mylib1", ["C:\\Users\\jbsid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\s\\mylib1.cpp"]),
    Pybind11Extension("mylib2", ["C:\\Users\\jbsid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\s\\mylib2.cpp"]),
]

setup(
    name="mylibs",
    version="0.0.1",
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
)

The final result:

You can as well generate the project for Visual Studio with CMake GUI:

If you do it with CMake GUI you can use this list CMake as reference:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(mylibs)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0148 NEW)


set(pybind11_DIR "C:/Users/jbsid/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/pybind11/share/cmake/pybind11")

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)


#add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(mylib1 mylib1.cpp)
pybind11_add_module(mylib2 mylib2.cpp)

Result (to include them all you can create a setup.py or package with PyInstaller or similar):

